# How do I calculate how many lines a given text takes up with a specified width in different screen resolutions?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

How do I calculate how many lines a given text takes up with a specified width?
And it is applicable to different screen resolutions？
My code:

```
int CStrUtils::TextLine(HDC hDC, HFONT hFont, const CString& strText, int nWidht)
{ 
    int nLine = 1;
    int nTextLength = strText.GetLength();
    CString strTextRemain = strText;
    HFONT hOldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hDC, (HGDIOBJ)hFont);
    SIZE sizeText = { 0 };
    
    int index = 1;
    while(strTextRemain.IsEmpty() == FALSE)
    {
        if (index > nTextLength)
        {
            break;
        }
        ++index;
        CString strTextTemp = strTextRemain.Left(index);
        GetTextExtentPoint32(hDC, strTextTemp, strTextTemp.GetLength(), &sizeText);
        if (sizeText.cx == nWidht)
        {
            ++nLine;
            strTextRemain = strTextRemain.Right(strTextRemain.GetLength() - index);
            index = 0;
        }
        else if (sizeText.cx > nWidht)
        {
            strTextRemain = strTextRemain.Right(strTextRemain.GetLength() - index + 1);
            index = 0;
            ++nLine;
        }
    }
    (HFONT)SelectObject(hDC, (HGDIOBJ)hOldFont);
    return nLine;
}
```

It works perfectly at 1920x1080, but at higher screen resolutions (2k or 4k) the calculation is wrong, it calculates one more line

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to calculate the number of lines for other purposes @AlexF

Comment: Re: `the calculation is wrong, it calculates one more line` - compared to WHAT? How do you output that `strText`?

Comment: Did the `nWidht` (input parameter) change at different resolutions?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Yes, it does！StrText is used to display in a label in a horizontal layout of duilib. The width of the horizontal layout is fixed, but the width value will change under different resolutions

Comment: @VladFeinstein StrText is used to display in a label in a horizontal layout of duilib. Sometimes the result of textline calculation is two lines, but on the interface, it only needs one line to be displayed

Comment: Could you show me how to call the function TextLine?